# SQL convert column headers to convert row values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

but what I am trying to achieve is this:

[image]

Please can anyone offer some much needed help to this SQL newbie.

Thanks

Comment: Its always better to share code not pics

Comment: Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your database model seems to be quite bad. You should have 2 tables and not only 1.

But anyway here is a solution

```
SELECT Jobno,
OPNo,
OperationType,
CASE OPNo
     WHEN 'OP1' then Op1
     WHEN 'OP2' then Op2
     WHEN 'OP3' then Op3
END as Operator
FROM pd
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.